# Postgres order of combined index

Tags: database, performance, postgresql, indexing

I have a table contains 10M lines data

```
CREATE TABLE log_info
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  created_date date, # date in month - max 30-31 distinct value
  dept_id integer, # max 50 distinct value
  group_id integer, # 10000 distinct value
  .......
)
```

Most queries are based on **created_date**, **dept_id** and **group_id**, so I want to create combined index for 3 fields

I know the order of combined index will effect to database performance, so in my case, which is the best index?

```
CREATE INDEX log_info_index1 ON log_info USING btree (created_date, dept_id, group_id);
```

or

```
CREATE INDEX log_info_index1 ON log_info USING btree (created_date, group_id, dept_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which order is best depends on what kind of queries are you planning to run. Consider the following examples:

```
WHERE created_date=? AND dept_id=?
WHERE created_date=? AND dept_id>=?
WHERE created_date=? AND dept_id=? AND group_id BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

For all of them, the index `(created_date, dept_id, group_id)` can be used, while the index `(created_date, group_id, dept_id)` cannot. In general, if you have an index on `(a,b,c)` then it can be used for the following cases

```
a=?
a=? AND b=?
a=? AND b=? AND c=?
a=? AND {comparison involving b}
a=? AND b=? AND {comparison involving c}
```

where comparison means one of `<`, `<=`, `between`.

If you know that you will never use comparisons, then you should put the columns with the most values first.

So for an example that combines the above 2 rules, suppose that you have columns `a`,`b`, and `c`. Assiditonally, assume that `b` can take only 5 different values (say 1 through 5), while `a` can take much more than 5 values. Funally, suppose that you only want run a query with something like

```
a=? AND b=? AND c>=?
```

then you should put `c` last (because of the comparison) and `a` before `b` because `a` has more values. Consequently you would have to use the following order: `(a,b,c)`.

Comment: If a have 5 different values, b have 100 different values, c have 5000 different values and the query a=? AND b=? AND c>=?. Which is the best order index? (a,b,c), (a,c,b), (c, b, a), ....

Comment: Then `(b,a,c)`.